How to sort product attribute options in magento 2 programatically
I have Magento 2.4.5 cloud edition.
I have a product attribute(brand) with 2000 options. When the Product is edited, the product options for a brand attribute are mixed up, and it is difficult to search to save an option for a product. So I want to sort these options alphabetically when we view at backend.

I was also in a similar situation like yours with my Magento Community Store where I had like 10000 options for a certain attribute which needed to be sorted alphabetically.
I took help of this following github based module
-> https://github.com/nhutnguyenvu/alphabet-option/tree/main/app/code/

In your Cloud Project
using SSH you can go to app/code
issue this command mkdir Eleadtech
git clone https://github.com/nhutnguyenvu/alphabet-option.git

mv app/code/*

rm -rf app/code (This command removes actually the extra app/code made inside the
Eleadtech directory)

